# $http.get method not working on ng-submit

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want $http.get method to work when a form is submitted.
Here is my code. The object $scope.questions is being set when the method is called but the data doesn't show up in the div. Moreover, when the $http.get method is outside the signIn() function it works just fine.

```js
$scope.signIn = function(data) {
  $location.path('/profile');
  var url = "database/fetch_data.php?query=";
  var query = "Select * from question where userId=2";
  url += query;
  $http.get(url).success(function(questionData) {
    $scope.questions = questionData;
    console.log($scope.questions);
  });

};
```

```html
<div>
  User Profile
  <br/>Question Posted
  <br/>
  <input ng-model="query.title" id="value" type="text" placeholder="Search by Title..." ">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="question in questions | filter: query ">
                {{question.title}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <br/>
</div>
```

Comment: why do u change your path in signIn function, second, where is your html code? that code is handled by the same controller that has signIn function ?

Comment: As i'm doing routing here I need to redirect to the /profile page on signIn() & display everything on that page. Yes the whole thing is under userController scope.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your `$location.path('/profile')` inside your http request. Remember that a http request is async call. You should redirect after getting the data not before.

```
$scope.signIn = function(data) {

  var url = "database/fetch_data.php?query=";
  var query = "Select * from question where userId=2";
  url += query;
  $http.get(url).success(function(questionData) {
    $scope.questions = questionData;
    console.log($scope.questions);
    $location.path('/profile');

  });

};
```

Comment: That is the first thing that i tried. Still no change.

Answer (score 0):

If you're redirecting to another route with a completely separate scope you will lose any scope you're setting in the success handling.

From what I'm reading you're clicking a button to do an action. After that action you're redirecting to another page with a separate controller and trying to persist the data.

Unfortunately, Angular hasn't figured out a great way to do this. The easiest way to persist data through controllers and scope is to create a service that will store it in one controller and grab it in another controller.

For instance:

```
$scope.signIn = function(data) {
  var url = "database/fetch_data.php?query=";
  var query = "Select * from question where userId=2";
  url += query;

  $http.get(url).success(function(questionData) {
    $location.path('/profile');
    storageService.store("question", questiondata)
  });
};
```

Your new factory to persist data through:

```
angular.module('moduleName').factory('storageService', [
    function () {
        return {
            store: function (key, value) {
                localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
            },

            get: function(key) {
                return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
            },

            remove: function(key) {
                localStorage.removeItem(key);
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Other controller to access data:

```
$scope.question = storageService.get("question");

// remove localstorage after you've grabbed it in the new controller
storageService.remove("question");
```

An alternative to doing the somewhat 'hacky' way of using localStorage to persist data through controllers is to use ui-router and have a resolve on the route you're redirecting to.

For instance:

```
$scope.signIn = function(data) {
  $state.go('profile');
};
```

In your route file:

```
.state('profile',  {
    url: '/profile'
    controller: profileControllerName,
    templateUrl: 'profileHtmlTemplate.html',
    resolve: {
      'questions': [function() {
         var url = "database/fetch_data.php?query=";
         var query = "Select * from question where userId=2";
         url += query;

         $http.get(url).success(function(res) {
            return res.data;
         });
      }]
    }
}
```

In your profile controller:

Inject your 'questions' resolve into your controller and assign `$scope.question = questions;

This will make the HTTP call as soon as you click the route, return the data if successful, then render the page. It will NOT render the page if the resolve does not return success. This will ensure your data will be loaded before you load the page that depends on that data.

I would highly recommend using services to hold your HTTP calls for specific parts of your application. If you have a GET questions, POST question, PUT question. I would create a questionService and make all my HTTP methods there so you don't have to clutter your routes. You would only have to call:

```
.state('profile',  {
    url: '/profile'
    controller: profileControllerName,
    templateUrl: 'profileHtmlTemplate.html',
    resolve: {
      'questions': [function() {
          return questionService.getQuestions(id).then(function(res) {
               return res.data;
          })
      }]
    }
}
```